# Prof of Reflexive, symmetric, or transitive relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, symmetric-groups

Consider the relation R on Z as: ∀m,n ∈Z, mRn ⇔ m − n is odd .      Is  R reflexive,    symmetric,
or  transitive? What would the proof or counter proof be?

Since R is a reflexive since m-n is linear, but I'm not sure how that would work with the proofs.

Comment: I answered this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554360/consider-the-relation-r-on-mathbb-z-as-forall-m-n-in-mathbbz-mrn-if/1554379#1554379

Comment: @AlvinJin Does your answer mean that the property is  reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive?

Comment: Not quite.  What do each of those terms mean? :)  I'll let you put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

Update: it is not true, but it is true for if the relation is $mRn \Leftrightarrow m-n$ is **even**

Let's prove the three properties:

> Reflexive: is it true that $mRm$ for all $m$?

Yes, $m-m=0 \Rightarrow mRm$, and 0 is even.

> Symmetric: if $mRn$, then $nRm$?

$mRn \Rightarrow m-n$ is even $\Rightarrow n-m$ is even (the opposite of an even is another even) $\Rightarrow nRm$

> Transitive: if $mRn$ and $nRp$, is it true that $mRp$?

We have $m-n$ and $n-o$ are both even numbers. Now $m-p = (m-n)+(n-o)$. Just realise that even plus even is even, so $m-p$ is even and therefore $mRp$

I think with this you can see why it is false for odd numbers.

Comment: $m-m=0$, but $0$ is not odd, so $mRm$ is not true...

Comment: And there's a problem with transitivity; $1 + 1$ isn't odd, for example.

Comment: Ups, no, I did even, it is not true for odd

Comment: Updated, I hope that clarifies the question, @ashleybee97